# Avoid csrf_token and use of @requires_csrf_token after @csrf_exempt

Tags: python, django

I have created a django project and setup urls.py, views models etc. All is working good except one thing.

urls.py snippet:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^$', main_page),
(r'^sendcall/$', sendcall),
(r'^dial_ag/$', dial_ag),
```

So my '/', '/sendcall/' are working fine as expected as they are getting POST request from my template forms and csrf_token are present there so no issues at all.

Now this /dial_ag/ url will never be called from my app. This url will be called by a third party API(I configured this url in their app so they will send POST request to this url). I figured out that in such a case the view **dial_ag** in **views.py** has to be used under decorator **@csrf_exempt** otherwise the third party will always get 403 forbidden response because I guess django is expecting even this to have csrf_token in the request?

So now I got it working but I read on stackoverflow itself about using @requires_csrf_token after @csrf_exempt to take care of security breach - a way to pass csrf_token internally somehow and protecting the view as:

```
@csrf_exempt
@requires_csrf_token
def my_protected_unprotected_view():
    ...
```

This is where I am stuck. I am unable to understand this concept or find a good documentation(Yes django documentation is not helping here.) about how to implement this. How from **urls.py** itself I will pass the token to the view so that I don't have to use only @csrf_exempt. The third party app has no relation with project except sending REQUEST to my url which is not supposed to have token but is using **@csrf_token** is the best way to handle such a situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If your third party app doesn't modify your data, you can prefer GET request.
- You can use @csrf_exempt since the third party app doesn't work on your page. But you should
  have proper authentication and authorization mechanism in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
"But you should have proper authentication and authorization mechanism in your code." Yes that API does provide a signature in the REQUEST HEADER which I can validate in my code confirming that the request is coming from that third party only. I would avoid GET request though. And do you have any reference example blog link etc about @requires_csrf_token?